# bash pipes - print certain cell from output

Tags: bash

I'm not sure if this is a very basic question or if I'm making progress, but what I'm trying (and failing) to do is compare two files with diff, then print a certain column from a selected row from the output. Basically one cell therefore is the output I want.

```
diff fileA fileB | ta=$(awk '{print $2}') | awk 'FNR==2'  $ta
```

obviously doesn't work because $ta isn't a file.

What's the best (easiest or fastest) way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you want to achieve, but this should do it

```
diff fileA fileB | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}'
```

Comment: that's it! thanks. I didn't know you could combine it like that. Cool.

Comment: @pepsimax It's `<pattern> { <action> }`, see [Getting Started with awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started) for example.